PIPX using latest Python 3.12 instead of system default
I am using pyenv for managing python installation in my system. Using pyenv I have installed python3.11.9 and set it as default with pyenv global 3.11.9, I have also added recommended commands by pyenv in my .zshrc file such that my system treats python 3.11.9 as default python.
Now, when I install pipx using brew install pipx, it also installs python3.12. And any installation done with pipx then uses python3.12 instead of system default 3.11.9.
How can I ensure that when I do brew install pipx? It installs using the default Python version instead of downloading the latest Python version.

the simpler is to use python3.11 -m pipx but you may find file pipx and it can be Python script with first line #!/usr/bin/env python3.12 and it may need to set 3.11. Other idea: use pip3.11 to install pipx again and it may replace version for 3.12. At least on Linux it works.

to use your interpreter as default for pipx you need to install pipx with it interpreter.
brew uninstall pipx
python3.11 -m pip install pipx

